What's the difference between 所有、全部都 and 全都
If it's possible could you gve some examples which show the difference between 所有、全部都 and 全都 and explain the usage of each?

When 所有 means 'all' 全部 is pretty much interchangeable, just where you put 都 depends.
所有: 一切; 全部 all
所有的材料都备齐了。
全部的材料都备齐了。(not 全部都的材料)
All the materials have been prepared.
所有代表都要佩戴徽章。
全部代表都要佩戴徽章。(not 全部都代表)
All the delegates must wear a badge.
警方对所有电话都做记录。
警方对全部电话都做记录。(not 全部都电话)
The police record all phone calls.


所有 (Which subject possessed) = all; own

Example: 你的所有資產 (all your assets); 政府所有 (owned by the government)

全部 - (All parts) = all

Example: 你的全部財富 (all your assets)

所有(都) = all (without exception)

全部(都) = all (without exception)

全都 is the short form of 全部都


Note:
"All" means "without exception", using 全部 and 都 together increases the emphasis

所有 - own; possess; all
全部/全 - whole; complete; total; entire; all
While they share similar meanings, slight differences do exist:

把你的所有(possession)全部(entirely)都給我 - Give me your entire possession = Give me all you have entirely.

Note: 都 also means 全. In 全部都/全都, it carries the message/emphasis that "nothing short of completeness".
